Isomorphic ESM package containing browser-specific, server-specific and shared code
I am trying to create an ESM package which contains browser-specific, server-specific and shared isomorphic javascript, such as:
src/
  browser.js
  server.js
  shared.js

I have a package.json using conditional exports:
"type": "module",
"exports": {
  "node": "./src/server.js",
  "default": "./src/browser.js"
}

In a separate project I can then import the package. Such as this example-browser.js JavaScript file:
import { shared, browser } from "esm-package-browser-server";
console.log(shared('Example'));
console.log(browser('Example'));

And html file:
<html>
  <script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "esm-package-browser-server": "./node_modules/esm-package-browser-server/src/browser.js"
      }
    }
  </script>
  <script type="module" src="example-browser.js"></script>
</html>

Server example-server.js JavaScript file:
import { shared, server } from "esm-package-browser-server";
console.log(shared('Example'));
console.log(server('Example'));

And run command:
node example-server.js

This appears to work in both environments. Questions I have:

Is this a "correct" way to create an isomorphic ESM package? If not, what should I change?
I had to use importmap linking to ./node_modules/esm-package-browser-server/src/browser.js is there a way to link to ./node_modules/esm-package-browser-server and infer browser.js from the exports? or better still no importmap at all?

Full source code is here:
https://github.com/kmturley/esm-package-browser-server

In short, yes this is the most modern way, As far as the browser support for exports in the web standard, there is none. This doesn't suck as much as it seems because anyone doing anything significant is using a bundler or other tooling that generates those import maps at build time. Or just straight up bundling and not using ESM apis (currently most common due to browser compat). What you have meets expectations. Maybe one note: there is a browser  key in exports as well which isn't the same meaning as default. Depends what you want -- this doesn't effect the core of your question.

Thanks good to know I am on the right track. I didn't use browser because of this line in the documentation: "Providing a "default" condition ensures that any unknown JS environments are able to use this universal implementation, which helps avoid these JS environments from having to pretend to be existing environments in order to support packages with conditional exports. For this reason, using "node" and "default" condition branches is usually preferable to using "node" and "browser" condition branches."
